# Java desktop app (awt/swing GUI) to Web app

Tags: java, swing, web, awt

I have a little game that I made (a runnable jar) and would like to put it on a website. I have 0 experience in writing a java web app, nor do I really want to rewrite the whole thing if it can be avoided.

Is there some way (a framework maybe) that will let me do something like this?

Comment: Drop inside a `JApplet` container instead of a `JFrame`

Comment: You may transform into JavaFX 2.0 app and run as web start application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a little game that I made (a runnable jar) and would like to put it on a website.

Launch it direct from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  There is no need to convert the code at all.

Comment: Does this keep the game in the browser, or is it like a popup?

Comment: Why would you want to keep the game embedded in a browser?  The frame ends up free floating on the desktop.  The user can change tabs in, minimize or end the browser and it will not affect the game.  What is the nature of the game, BTW?  A FPS, a maze exploration style game,  a 2D scroller..?

Comment: It's a minesweeper type thing, I am going to add a system of points soon, where you earn points by winning games, then you can bet those points to earn more if you win, or lose them if you lose.

Comment: @jorisbolsens: Here's a basic [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).

Comment: @trashgod  Given sub-way is an hybrid application/applet, I'm worried it will confuse the OP into thinking they need to change the code.  But I guess you meant the JWS part of it as the example.